# Using strcat for permissions in C

Tags: c

Please help, going insane, been trying to do this for 8 hours now and it never works. I realise I can print out the permissions of a file easily, I've managed to do that, but I can't use this method to return it.

```
char *printMode(mode_t mode) {
    char *myString = (char *)calloc(11, sizeof(char));

    mode_s = ((S_ISDIR(mode)) ? "d" : "-");
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-"));
    strcat(mode_s, ((mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-"));

    return myString;
}
```

Comment: `mode_s = ((S_ISDIR(mode)) ? "d" : "-")` overwrite the `calloc`ated memeory.... so all `strcat` are UB

Comment: change `mode_s = ((S_ISDIR(mode)) ? "d" : "-");` by `strcpy(mode_s, S_ISDIR(mode) ? "d" : "-");`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
char *mode_s = (char *) calloc(MODE_S_LEN, sizeof(char));
mode_s = ((S_ISDIR(mode)) ? "d" : "-");
```

The first one make `mode_s` point to the memory you allocate. The next line makes it point to either `"d"` or `"-"`. You reassign the pointer and make it point somewhere else.

Since you initialize the memory you allocate to zero, you could use `strcat` here too. Or `strcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

When you go to add the directory flag, you are reassigning `mode_s` to a string constant, throwing away the allocated memory.

You need to use `strcpy` in this case to copy the characters.

```
strcpy(mode_s, ((mode & S_ISDIR) ? "d" : "-"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize mode_s to `"d"` or `"-"` in the first test. The subsequent calls to `strcat()` invoke undefined behavior as string literals should not be modified and would be too short for `strcat()` anyway.

You could avoid this kind of mistake by increasing the warning level: `gcc -Wall -W` would tell you about storing a constant string pointer into a regular `char *`.

Your method is quite inefficient, Here is a simpler and faster alternative:

```
char *printMode(mode_t mode) {
    char buf[11];
    int i = 0;

    buf[i++] = S_ISDIR(mode) ? 'd' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IXUSR) ? 'x' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IXGRP) ? 'x' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-';
    buf[i++] = (mode & S_IXOTH) ? 'x' : '-';
    buf[i++] = '\0';

    return strdup(buf);
}
```